# identical picture file has different size in different computer

Tags: filesize, stat

I am developing a IM software, in which you can send pictures. Recently I had met a weird problem: the same picture(have the same md5 checksum), when picked up to send through my software, and in my software, I read different file size.

In my computer, the software read the correct size of 7489 bytes, but in my customer's computer,  it's size is 8700 bytes. Both OS is Win7 Premium version, and use C `stat` method to get file size.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: can you get the file format. Can you check if the size is in KB or Kb. Can you try transferring the file from your client's machine to your own machine? Are you sure the IM is not compressing or altering the image in any way while it is being transferred to the client? How are you transferring the image, can give more details.

Comment: file format is PNG. When i move mouse over picture, both system told the correct size of 7.31KB. I wrote the transfer code so i am sure the file will not be altered. When you pick up a picture throw the IM attachment button, i get the file path, and then i check file size.

Answer (score 0):

It is too long for a comment, I hope it reaches the quality of an answer. :)

Check the file system type and the allocation unit size on the file systems as well. It is normal that the same file have different reported size on different file systems. Also different software reports the size differently. Some reports the useful data amount, others, report "the size of the file on the disk". Which describes how many space does it consume. It should be an integer multiple of the allocation unit size. I guess 7489 bytes is the size of the real useful data, and 8700 bytes are the size on the disk. Although it is a bit unusual since the allocation unit size used to be a multiple of 512 bytes, but on SSD it might not be a rule anymore. So I think you should not worry about it. It is something like a rounding error, and if your checksums are the same then the files are identical.

Ps: In explorer right click -> properties will show both the useful size of the file and its size on the disk, so you can compare.